# How to hidden all application shortcut from in home screen?

Tags: android

My Android Emulator displays lot of the application shortcut. How to hidden all application shortcut from in the home screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't**. You can not control third party application behavior within your application. Also you don't have any rights for Home Screen within your application. Manually deletion those applications from **Setting application** is the one option.

Comment: Ok. How to hidden my application shortcut. Any idea.

Comment: I am deleted my application from settings.  After i am seeing  the home screen. My application shortcut is does not removed.

Comment: When you uninstall any application from Setting, the shortcut associated with that application automatically removed from Launcher screen.